# local HTML file not loaded in Chrome for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, local-files

Trying to load a local HTML file (SPA including assets, js, css) on Chrome on Android. File is loaded, html seems to be parsed but shows nothing.
When debugging this remotely (USB/adb) I got this error in the console:

```
 Not allowed to load local resource: content://com.huawei.filemanager.share.fileprovider/root/storage/emulated/0/Download/test1/index.html
```

Basically it seems the file is not loaded at all.

What can be done ? Help, Tx.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the code, my friend, I tested it with other html/blank/empty files - the same error. Tried also on Edge and Firefox. Same.

Comment: Show the code where you try to load that content scheme in Chrome. Also tell how you obtained that scheme.

Comment: I think it's a misunderstanding here. (probably my poor english). What "scheme" ?  Again: there is no code involved, for any html file the same error above.

Comment: Obviously it's a problem of permissions, even for all these browsers I let full permissions. I am not an mobile/Android expert. The device is Huawei P40 Pro and Android version is 11.

Comment: `What "scheme" ? ` I said content scheme and you posted one: `content://com.huawei.filemanager.share.filepr........`  And if there is no code involved then tell where you got that content scheme and how you use it for Chrome.